# How do you prove that in a circle the angle subtended at the cente is proportional to its arc length using symmetry?

Tags: trigonometry

Firstly, I have seen some other posts which ask the same question but none of them have an elaborate explanation as to how symmetry helps us realise this, which is what I am looking for. My trigonometry textbook too is vague when it comes to this.

> By the symmetry of the circle we may assume that the  $\angle AOP$ subtended at the centre $O$ of the circle is proportional to the length of the arc itself (we cannot assume such a thing for an ellipse, in which equal arcs generally subtend unequal angles at the centre).

I find the symmetry part of the explanation really very vague. Can someone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 1):

What your highlighted sentence tries to convey is the following: In our geometry there are certain distinguished curves, called *circles*, and there are certain distinguished maps, called *rotations*, which map some family of concentric circles to themselves. Since rotations around a point $O$ seem to preserve (i) our intuitive notion of "angle" between two rays emanating from $O$, as well as (ii) the arc length of circles around $O$ having the same radius, we may as well take the length of such arcs as measure for this precarious concept of "angle".

Answer (score 0):

A circle has perfect rotational symmetry. That means that you can tilt a circle through any angle and it looks like the same circle.

Your textbook is saying that it doesn't matter where on the circle you place the angle. The relationship between the angle and the arc length is the same. If you draw an ellipse and place the same angle at different points on the ellipse you will see that the same angle can correspond to different arc lengths.